# Extracting two numerical characters of a string and and placing them in an integer (C Programming)

Tags: c, string

Code segment below to extract the first two numerical characters of string str[] and place them into i1 as the decimal value they denote and extract the last two numerical characters of string str and place them into i2 as the decimal value they denote; such that the print statement at the bottom will print 12 and 67 to the screen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
char str[]="1234567";
int i1, i2;
//write code here
printf("%d %d\n, i1, i2);
}
```

I am stuck with what to do. I am assuming I am suppose to use `strcat(i1, i2)` but I am not getting `12` and `67` when I print it out.

What is the solution to this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You must have tried something? Show your code and say what it prints.

Comment: And what to we know about str? Do you only have to solve the problem for that particular string, or should it work for different lengths? Will str only contain digits, or could it be other characters too?

Comment: `i1 = 10*(str[0]-'0') + str[1]-'0';`

Comment: "I am assuming I am suppose to use `strcat(i1,i2)`...." Why are you assuming this? `strcat()` expects pointers to strings for arguments, and `i1` and `i2` are `int`s. If you have code that is not working, you should post it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what if string starts with zero?

Comment: @user5250644 if `"0123456"` then print `1`. I think so. You should ask his professor about the required specifications. Not me.

Comment: If that is the template your were given to fill out: you can't use `strcat` (which is irrelevant anyway) and you can't use `strlen` (which might be relevant), because there is no `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: The initial two digits are relatively easy. The last two digits will require you to walk the string and remember the previous two digits found, until the `'\0'` string terminator is reached.

Comment: @WeatherVane If other parts can not be changed,  This code can not be compiled because `"` is missing. Also You can write `#include <string.h>` in the part of _write code here_ (After the next line). ;-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY valid points! But how to educate the esteemed professor who likes `main()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Probably it is speculated that the professor is watching here. :D

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the wise professor will learn as much from the students as from the professor's course, so many years ago.

Comment: Here is my code using pointers. I am only obtaining 2 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric character codes are guaranteed to be in a series
(from `0` to `9`. E.g `'0' + 1` become `'1'`),
so you can convert them to numbers by subtracting `'0'`.
Also Since the end of the string has NUL characters(`'\0'` or simply `0`),
you can find the last two letters by looking for it.
(E.g. `str[index] == '\0'` or `str[index] == 0` or simply `!str[index]`)
So on the whole it can be written as one example as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char str[]="1234567";
    int i1, i2;

    #define dc2i(dc) ( dc - '0' ) //convert one digit character to int
    #define d22i( s) ( 10*dc2i(*s) + dc2i(s[1]) ) //two digit to int
    {
        const char *i1p = str, *i2p;
        //Is it necessary to check if the whole is composed only of numeric characters?
        if(!*str || !str[1]){//Is it length of 2 or more? (Do you need a length of 4 or more?)
            fprintf(stderr, "'%s' is too short string.", str);
            return 1;
        }
        for(const char *p = str; *p && p[1]; ++p)
            i2p = p;//save last pointer
        i1 = d22i(i1p);
        i2 = d22i(i2p);
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", i1, i2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string has a length equal to or larger than four, and consists only of numerical digits, this piece of code should do the trick. Your assumption was not wrong though, your problem can indeed be solved with the strcat() function, but it is slightly longer and a little more complicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main(){
  char str[]="1234567";
  int i1, i2;
  i1 = (str[0] - '0') * 10 + (str[1] - '0');
  int length = strlen(str);
  i2 = (str[length - 2] - '0') * 10 + (str[length - 1] - '0');
  printf("%d %d\n", i1, i2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The string only needs to be of length 2. I would like to know how this can be solved with `strcat` when the program template prints `int` types.

Answer (score 0):

While you can convert directly to `i1` and `i2` with a manual convert from character to int, `stdlib.h` provides the `strto..` family of functions to preform the conversion for you while providing error checking. (e.g. `strtol`, `strtoul`, etc..). While the conversion itself is fairly trivial, always check if a standard library function already does what you are attempting to do. Chances are, if one exists, it has had decades of use and validation and will probably preform quite a bit better than what you reinvent.

Taking this route, your task become simply creating substrings of `str` containing the needed digits, and then passing the substrings to `strtol` for conversion to `int` (while `strtol` returns a `long` value, given the explicit definition of `str` in this case, there is no potential for exceeding the storage capacity of `int` and no possibility of encountering something other than digits in the string) As such, a simple check of `errno` can provide assurance that a conversion from `str` to `long` took place and a cast to `int` will resolve the type difference.

Putting those pieces together, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

enum { NCHR = 2, NOFF = 5 };    /* constants, no. chars, i2 offset */

int main (void) {

    char str[]="1234567",
        buf1[NCHR + 1] = "",  /* buffer to hold substrings */
        buf2[NCHR + 1] = "";  /* initialized to provide termination */
    int i1 = 0,
        i2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NCHR; i++) {    /* fill substrings */
        buf1[i] = str[i];               /* buf1[] = "12"   */
        buf2[i] = str[i + NOFF];        /* buf2[] = "67"   */
    }

    errno = 0;                          /* initialize errno     */
    i1 = (int)strtol (buf1, NULL, 10);  /* perform converstions */
    i2 = (int)strtol (buf2, NULL, 10);

    if (errno) {    /* validate errno remains 0 or handle error */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed converstion for i1 or l2.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("i1 = %d\ni2 = %d\n", i1, i2);

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** both `buf1` and `buf2` must end with the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` (or equivalently `0`). Termination is insured by initializing all characters in each to `0` when they are declared -- and not overwriting the final `0` during use in  your code.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/subst2int
i1 = 12
i2 = 67
```

Either way you choose to approach the problem is fine. No one way is more-correct than then other as long as your code is valid (you can worry about optimizations and tweaking the number of instructions well down the road in your learning of C). Look things over in all answers, and let any of the authors know if you have questions.